# Jquery Show() flicker

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var oauth = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().oauth;
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#note
{
display:none;
}
</style>
<script src="Task.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Taskhandle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>TaskMan</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="title"><input type="text" id="note">
<a href="" id="make" onclick="maketask()">+</a> <a href="" id="anote">N</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
$('#anote').click(function () { 
$('#note').show();
});
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this code in chrome the input flickers in and out. I need a fix.

Comment: I guess you have to give us the code to task.js

Answer (score 0):

You have to prevent default of the link (which is reloading the page):

```
$('#anote').click(function (E) { 
   E.preventdefault();
   $('#note').show();
});
```

Comment: That does not help. Now it does not even flicker.

Comment: @jbills - isn't that what you wanted -- for it to not flicker?

Comment: Your solution made it do nothing at all.